# How to interpolate variable within a string in VueJS

Tags: json, vue.js, httprequest, string-interpolation

I would like to interpolate a string in VueJS which contains variables and html. Is there any option in Vue?

component.vue

```
<template>
    <div v-html="test1"></div>
</template>


<script>
export default {
  name: 'component',
  data() {
    return {
      test: "test interpolation",
      test1: " <p> some text {{ test }} </p>",
    };
  },
}
</script>
```

String in test1 variable is loaded from a Json file after an Http request

Comment: Have a look at https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

Answer (score 0):

```
export default {
    data () {
      return {
        rawHtml: "<h1> This is some HTML </h1>",
      }
    },
    render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <div domPropsInnerHTML={this.rawHtml}> </div>
          </div>
        )
      }
}
```

- domPropsInnerHTML attribute performs the same task as v-html , it sets the content of the div to rawHtml.

[Ref for more](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-jsx-with-vue/)

[More Example](https://medium.com/js-dojo/using-jsx-with-vue-js-846f4fbbf07f)